# Date from string not working with specific date

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdateformatter

I have a very strange issue about one specific date 10-18-15 using xcode 7.01

Running code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *stringDate =@"10-18-15";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;

    NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];

    NSLog(@"Mydate:%@ Text: %@",myDate,stringDate);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

output:

2015-10-20 10:37:55.129 teste[3286:95083] Mydate:(null) Text: 10-18-15

If I change `NSString *stringDate =@"10-17-15";`

output:

`2015-10-20 10:22:10.741 teste[3102:82782] Mydate:2015-10-17 03:00:00 +0000 Text: 10-17-15`

It seems this date 10-18-2015 is corrupted in `NSDate` database

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I also get `(null)` for 10-17-15. The only way it works for me is to change the middle number to < 12 (aka `dd-MM-yy`)

Comment: Are you aware that printing `NSDate` objects directly using `NSLog()` will show their date/time in the GMT timezone?  For the 70,000th time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found same question: Bug in swift 2.0 NSDateFormatter?The behavior depends on which timeZone the formatter using. For example: America/Sao_Paulo In Sao Paulo, timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/sao-paulo?year=2015 Sunday, 18 October 2015, 00:00:00 clocks are turned forward 1 hour to Sunday, 18 October 2015, 01:00:00 local daylight time instead That means, there is no 2015-10-18 00:00:00 in Sao Paulo. And as for NSDateFormatter, when it receives no time information from string, it assumes the time is 00:00:00 in its timezone. That's why it returns nil.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** It's critical to set the calendar property of the date formatter!

Conversion from string to date may fail for specific dates because some dates simply do not exist in certain time zones (e.g. BRT) due to daylight saving time switch happening on midnight. So there is no midnight actually and `10-18-15 00:00 (BRT)` (when no time is specified midnight is presumed) is just not a valid date.

However, when a calendar object is specified (only tested it with the Gregorian calendar) the date formatter seems to become "smarter" and falls back to the start of the day, which is `10-18-15 1:00 AM`, instead of returning `nil`.

```
NSString *stringDate = @"10-18-15";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM-dd-yy";
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
```

Here is some code that shows the behaviour. I used a Xcode Playground, so it's in Swift...

```
import UIKit

func printDateForString(string: String, dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter, timeZone: NSTimeZone? = nil) {
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
    print("result: ", terminator: "")
    if let date = date {
        let outputDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        outputDateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
        outputDateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
        outputDateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        outputDateFormatter.timeZone = timeZone
        print(outputDateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))
    }
    else {
        print("nil")
    }
}

let dateString = "10-18-15"
let dateFormat = "MM-dd-yy"
let timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "America/Sao_Paulo")!

print("configure date formatter without setting its calendar property")
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
dateFormatter.timeZone = timeZone
printDateForString(dateString, dateFormatter: dateFormatter, timeZone: timeZone)

print("after setting date formatter's calendar property to non-nil (Gregorian)")
dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
printDateForString(dateString, dateFormatter: dateFormatter, timeZone: timeZone)

print("resetting calender property of date formatter to nil")
dateFormatter.calendar = nil
printDateForString(dateString, dateFormatter: dateFormatter, timeZone: timeZone)
```

Output:

> configure date formatter without setting its calendar property
>   result: nil
>   after setting date formatter's calendar property to non-nil (Gregorian)
>   result: 10/18/15, 1:00 AM
>   resetting calender property of date formatter to nil
>   result: nil

**Original answer:**

You should set the date format explicitly when converting from string to date:

```
NSString *stringDate = @"10-18-15";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM-dd-yy";
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
```

Comment: Obviously not, from what the OP shows in his question.  He's just looking at the converted date object wrong.

Comment: I copy and tried your suggestion and still having null output: 2015-10-20 12:01:40.322 teste[4811:166198] Mydate:(null) Text: 10-18-15, 2015-10-20 14:01:40 +0000

Comment: My question is why isn't working only with day 10/18/15 ? Any other day even 10/18/14 output correctly: 2015-10-20 12:13:40.833 teste[5216:178755] Mydate:2014-10-18 03:00:00 +0000 Text: 10/18/14

Comment: I don't know what is specific about that date. But I recall a similar problem with `NSDateFormatter`. It turned out that everything works as expected only when I set the `calendar`, `timeZone`, or `locale` property (cannot remember which one it was actually) of the date formatter object.

Comment: You are right ! I found same question:  Bug in swift 2.0 NSDateFormatter?The behavior depends on which timeZone the formatter using.

For example: America/Sao_Paulo

In Sao Paulo, http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/sao-paulo?year=2015

Sunday, 18 October 2015, 00:00:00 clocks are turned forward 1 hour to Sunday, 18 October 2015, 01:00:00 local daylight time instead
That means, there is no 2015-10-18 00:00:00 in Sao Paulo.

And as for NSDateFormatter, when it receives no time information from string, it assumes the time is 00:00:00 in its timezone. That's why it returns nil.

Comment: Well spotted! You should also post this as an answer in addition to your comment, so it can be found more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give NSdate to this format which returns  date which can be converted later either to NSDate/NSString in short format

For example:

```
    NSDate *stringDate=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;

    NSString *myDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:stringDate];
```

If you want to use NSString anyway, then convert it to NSdate and parse it to the formatter.

Comment: I change to stringDate to "10/18/15" and still output null but changing to "10/17/15" or "10/19/15" output: Mydate:2015-10-17 03:00:00 +0000 Text: 10/17/15 or 2015-10-20 11:38:16.584 teste[4312:148794] Mydate:2015-10-19 02:00:00 +0000 Text: 10/19/15